# django 500.html on prodserver not showing up - instead 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, apache

I am deploying django page and finally it is up running, but 500 template is not found in production server and i am getting this error in `var/log/apache2/error.log`:

```
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)
TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

I have created 500.html and 404.html Templates and they are under `templates` directory. and this is my settings.py

```
import os
gettext = lambda s: s
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "templates",
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates"),
)
```

what am i missing? why is 500.html not found by server even if it is there?

Comment: Please try random path like '/sdfjlksjfdsd' on your site , please let me know what happened? Did you put DEBUG=False in your settings.py file?

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy, yes, i put ``DEBUG=False``. if i change this to ``True``, i am getting normal error traceback, but this shouldnot be in prod server.

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy, what do you mean with another path? instead ``templates`` another path?

Comment: i was just simulating 404.html functionality. If you give some random path, it should show 404.html right? try that. let me know is 404.html working ?

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy, yes, 404 is working.

Comment: Then it shouldn't have any problem to show 500.html. something is missing. i am not sure.

Comment: Please try to make sure your 500.html doesn't contain any references to things that don't exist yet (a 500 error is rendered before any context processors for instance). Try using a simple: `<html><body><h1>500 Error raised in django!</h1></body></html>`

Comment: Can you share the 500 template with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
by getting the same issue before i simple replace like this :    

import os
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates').replace('\\','/'),
```

)

Comment: How did the above solve the issue? If teems that if templates dir was wrong, both 404 and 500 wouldn't work, would they?

Answer (score 0):

correct spelling, Try templates not template?

Comment: what do you mean? i am using ``templates`` and not template.

Comment: in your question you wrote: _Templates and they are under `template` directory_

Comment: @tutuDajuju, oh yeah, sorry, this was a typo

Comment: @doniyor: please see latest comment in your question for more trial and error

Comment: @tutuDajuju, yeah, my 500.html contains only some text and nothing which needs db or any outer connection

Comment: It's not about outer connections, make sure it doesn't contain anything except simple html (no django tags), and try again. Test it locally by setting DEBUG=False and raising an exception. For more guidelines [read the docs on 500 error](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-500-server-error-view)

Comment: @tutuDajuju i mean with outer connection anything which needs db and backend. i already tried that, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

A similar error can be caught when using Google app Engine.
True, template should be in plural "templates"
A common mistake is to include the template directory in the yaml file

```
- url: /templates
  static_dir: templates
```

If you remove those two lines your code will work just fine assuming that your path is the following:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/home.html')
```